# Easier way to do nested for loops?

Tags: python, for-loop

So in a lot of my coding problems, I end up doing something along the lines of:

```
for i in range(10):
    for j in range(10):
        for k in range(10):
            print(i, j, k)
```

I was just wondering if there was a simpler way to iterate through multiple ranges of numbers? I want to have it so I can give an argument of `4` in my function and it iterates through 4 different numbers.

I know that:

```
for i, j in range(10):
    print(i, j)
```

will iterate through `i` and `j` at the same time.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `for i,j in range(10):` will raise an error.

Comment: See `itertools.product`

Answer (score 3):

You can use `itertools.product` to do this, it will effectively write the nested loops for you, but it's not more efficient as far as I know, it's mostly just more convenient:

```
from itertools import product
for i, j, k in product(range(10), range(10), range(10)):
    print(i, j, k)
```

EDIT: As @interjay pointed out, the `repeat=` argument might also be useful to you. I assumed you might not always use the same iterator for i, j, and k, but your example can be simplified further like this:

```
for i, j, k in product(range(10), repeat=3):
    print(i, j, k)
```

The [`itertools` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) has lots of convenient ways to manipulate and combine iterators.

Comment: The `repeat=` argument seems to be what OP is looking for.

Comment: Thank you for this solution! I'm not very experienced in terms of 'efficient' coding and so its interesting for me to see that it is more efficient time-wise to simply write the 3 loops down as I stated in the questions vs using the itertools product method. I am always baffled by the concept that less code != more efficient!

Comment: In terms of efficiency, both options have to do the same work, you're still O(n^3) either way. If itertools is implemented in C rather than pure Python, it might be faster, but only by a constant factor.. It's going to take cubic time no matter what.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
def loop_fun(loop_number, *args):
    if loop_number:
        for i in range(10):
            loop_fun(loop_number-1, i, *args)
            if loop_number == 1:
                print(*args, i)


loop_fun(4)
```

Comment: Thank you for this function! I am just starting to look at these "recursive" style functions, it's very fascinating. I don't quite understand how this works but I can see the use in using this in some of my niche cases!